# cdk deploy option to re-build image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I am deploying a new stack using AWS Fargate, I am using the cdk in python.

The docker image is build and push in ECR when I do `cdk deploy` but when I do a change in my entrypoint.sh that is copied in my Dockerfile, the cdk does not detect this change.

So cdk command ends with "no changes".

**How to re-build and update the docker image with the cdk?**

This is my code to create the service

```py
back = aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
    self,
    "back",
    cpu=256,
    task_image_options=aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedTaskImageOptions(
        image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_asset('./back'),
    ),
    desired_count=2,
    memory_limit_mib=512,
    public_load_balancer=True,
)
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt update && apt install -y python3-dev libpq-dev wait-for-it

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to reuse the same docker tag, that won't work with most container orchestration tools. Each time you rebuild the docker image it needs a new tag and you'll need to update the tag in your task definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `./back` directory was a symbolic link.

This change did the trick:

```py
image=ecs.ContainerImage.from_asset(
    './back',
    follow_symlinks=cdk.SymlinkFollowMode.ALWAYS,
),
```